# installing Java6 EE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, installation

How do I install Java 6 EE ? Is it like First I install Java SE6 jdk & then install java EE6 sdk. In such case, do I need to use same folder?

Comment: Just goto http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html and select Java EE(the last option) and download it. Thats all you need to do!

Comment: @Apache Fan as installation instructions for Java EE say Java EE 6 SDK distributions require JDK release 6. So does this 'JDK + Java EE Bundle' link includes both?
What if I have already jdk6 installed on windows my pc?

Comment: Yes it includes both. You can check if JRE is already installed by going to Add Remove programs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The installation instructions are [here](http://java.sun.com/javaee/sdk/javaee6sdk_install.jsp).

Comment: +1 for pointing to the authoritative source.  (-1 for beating me to it.  OK, j/k on that point.)

Answer (score 2):

Download a Java EE 6 container - Glassfish is a good candidate. That's the Java EE 6 SDK for you. And no, you shouldn't use the same folder.

Comment: A Java EE container is not the same thing as the SDK. The SDK comes with GlassFish, but GlassFish does not com with the SDK.

Comment: True. But you can't really use the SDK without a container, if you're actually intending to use it; you're still better off downloading the container you intend to use. And for Java EE - that should be glassfish IMHO.

Comment: That's why the SDK ships with GlassFish.

Comment: Err... that url doesn't say a single thing about Glassfish not serving as a fully capable SDK for Java EE. If you have Glassfish, you have Java EE locally; that's enough to develop Java EE 6. Any specific SDK would be unnecessary, and downloading the JDK and glassfish would be more than enough to start developing Java EE 6.

Comment: @Joseph Ottinger THANK YOU, 
I find Apache Fan's link is correct but requires jre to be explicitly installed ...